# python ternary in jinja2 gives TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a table and I want to change background color of tr if value of person.storyPublished is true otherwise do nothing.

My code looks like this:

```
 {% for person in people %}
    <tr class="row-person {% '.row-story-published' if  person.storyPublished  else ' ' %}" >
    <td>
    {{ person.name }}
    </td>
    ...
```

I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected
```

and the CSS part is here:

```
<style>
    .row-story-published{
        background-color: #b3ffb3;
    }
</style>
```

why is this happening? What i miss that I don't notice? Any help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You used "{% %}" which wants to get a tag like if, endif etc.
If you just want to execute a piece of python code, like your ternary expression, you should use double braces like so

```
{{ 'row-story-published' if  person.storyPublished  else ' ' }}
```

Comment: Wow, that works, I did not know a python expression like if else could be used with double braces. Do you know if it only works with Jinja? Or Django too? Thanks +1

Comment: Sorry I am using flask, so I can only say that it works with jinja. But why should this differ in Django? Does Django not use pure jinja?

Comment: No Django have its own template language, it is like Jinja but there are differences.

Comment: thank you that works except i have to remove the dot at CSS class

Answer (score 2):

Template language is different than Python, so has different syntax. You cannot use Python's idiomatic syntax in templates.

```
<tr class="row-person {% if  person.storyPublished %} row-story-published {% endif %}" >
```